# How to catch error conditions in a http service in angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http

```
manageHttp(method: any, url: any, body: any) {
    this.headers = this.config.setHeaders();
    var urlto = this.config.serverUrl + '' + url;
    if (method === 'get') {
        this.toRunMethod = this.http.get(urlto, { headers: this.headers });
    } else if (method === 'post') {
        this.toRunMethod = this.http.post(this.config.serverUrl + url, body, { headers: this.headers });
    } else if (method === 'put') {
        this.toRunMethod = this.http.put(this.config.serverUrl + url, body, { headers: this.headers });
    } else if (method === 'delete') {
        this.toRunMethod = this.http.delete(this.config.serverUrl + url, { headers: this.headers });
    }
    return this.toRunMethod.map((response: Response) => {
        // More than one user - logout
        if (response && response.json().error_code == 0) {
            return response.json();
        }
    }, (error) => {
        this.authGuardMethod(error);
    });
}
```

The response in my network is just like this

```
{error: "token_expired"}
```

But unfortunately it is not getting catched by my authGuardMethod() method,I mean it is not going into this condition

```
}, (error) => {
        this.authGuardMethod(error);
    });
```

Its not even going into authGaurd Method,any how my code,

```
 authGuardMethod(error: any) {
    if (error) {
        if (error.statusText === "Unauthorized") {
            let url =  this.router.url.split("/");
            if(url.length > 1){
                if(url[1] != 'estimate-assembly-cost' && url[1] != 'placeorder' ){
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                }
            }
            localStorage.setItem("error", '1');
        } else if(error.statusText === "Bad Request") {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
            localStorage.removeItem('adminUser');
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
        }
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("error", '2');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}
```

I have been struggling to find this but no luck.

Comment: post authGuardMethod() code here

Comment: `(error)` handler should work

Comment: @Aravind,yes but it is not even going inside of it.

Comment: @MMR it will work if there is an error.

Comment: You are returning a JSON payload with a field called `"error"`, that's not the same thing as returning an error. I bet your `{error: "token_expired"}` is returned with an HTTP status `200`?

Answer (score -1):

From my view the best way to work on error during request is to create an interceptor and handle error request at global level.

https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses

Hope it will help.